# How to translate the items in ExtJS?

Tags: extjs, extjs4.2

I am using ExtJS and I added some items such as pickerdate, buttons... I would like to translate those items into my native language since by default they are in English.

I have been searching about it and I found that I should have files for internationalization, but I do not have them since I do only have these two files:

`index.html`

```
<html> 
  <head>
        <!-- <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"> -->
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

        <title>Test</title>

        <!-- CDN 4.2.1- NEPTUNE -->
        <link href="http://cdn.sencha.io/ext/gpl/4.2.1/resources/css/ext-all-neptune.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <script src="http://cdn.sencha.com/ext/gpl/4.2.1/ext-all.js"></script>
        <link href="http://cdn.sencha.io/ext/gpl/4.2.1/resources/css/ext-all-neptune.css" rel="stylesheet" />

        <!-- JScript -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/js/app.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
    </body>

</html>
```

`app.js`

```
    Ext.application({
        name: 'MyApp',
        launch: function() {            
            const datePickers = Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
                renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
                width: 300,
                bodyPadding: 10,
                items: [{
                    xtype: 'datefield',
                    format: 'd/m/Y',
                    anchor: '100%',
                    fieldLabel: 'Check In:',
                    name: 'from_date',
                    minValue: new Date(),
                    listeners: {
                        'change': function(me) {

                        }
                    }
                }, {
                    xtype: 'datefield',
                    format: 'd/m/Y',
                    anchor: '100%',
                    fieldLabel: 'Check Out:',
                    name: 'to_date',
                    minValue: new Date(),
                    listeners: {
                        'change': function(me) {

                        }
                    }
                }]
            });

            Ext.create('Ext.container.Viewport', {
                items: [{
                    title: 'Y',
                    region: 'west',
                    collapsible: true,
                    split: true,
                    titleCollapse: true,
                    items: [{
                        items: datePickers
                    }],
                }]
            });
        }
    });
```

So as you can see, English is the default language for those datepickers:

[image]

Is there a way to translate them into a desired language? I would only need to translate the month and the "today" button but if there is a complete translation, it would be better.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it simple by override the `Ext.picker.Date`. Just change `Ext.locale.en.picker.Date` to your name eg. `Ext.locale.pl.picker.Date` and change parameters like below:

```
Ext.define("Ext.locale.en.picker.Date", {
    override: "Ext.picker.Date",
    todayText: "Today",
    minText: "This date is before the minimum date",
    maxText: "This date is after the maximum date",
    disabledDaysText: "",
    disabledDatesText: "",
    nextText: 'Next Month (Control+Right)',
    prevText: 'Previous Month (Control+Left)',
    monthYearText: 'Choose a month (Control+Up/Down to move years)',
    todayTip: "{0} (Spacebar)",
    format: "m/d/y",
    startDay: 0
});
```

To translate other date strings:

```
if (Ext.Date) {
    Ext.Date.monthNames = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];

    Ext.Date.getShortMonthName = function (month) {
        return Ext.Date.monthNames[month].substring(0, 3);
    };

    Ext.Date.monthNumbers = {
        January: 0,
        Jan: 0,
        February: 1,
        Feb: 1,
        March: 2,
        Mar: 2,
        April: 3,
        Apr: 3,
        May: 4,
        June: 5,
        Jun: 5,
        July: 6,
        Jul: 6,
        August: 7,
        Aug: 7,
        September: 8,
        Sep: 8,
        October: 9,
        Oct: 9,
        November: 10,
        Nov: 10,
        December: 11,
        Dec: 11
    };

    Ext.Date.getMonthNumber = function (name) {
        return Ext.Date.monthNumbers[name.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + name.substring(1, 3).toLowerCase()];
    };

    Ext.Date.dayNames = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"];

    Ext.Date.getShortDayName = function (day) {
        return Ext.Date.dayNames[day].substring(0, 3);
    };

    Ext.Date.parseCodes.S.s = "(?:st|nd|rd|th)";

    Ext.Date.firstDayOfWeek = 0;
    Ext.Date.weekendDays = [6, 0];
}
```

To change month header to 3 letters you need to change `renderTpl` in Ext.picker.Date.

Do something like that:

```
Ext.define('Ext.override.picker.Date', {
    override: "Ext.picker.Date",
    getDayInitial: function (value) {
        return value.substr(0, 3);
    }
});
```

Changed the `getDayInitial` function to render 3 letters.

Comment: Perfect! It works. However, this does not translate the months (January, February, March...). Is there a way to translate them?

Comment: Look edited answer to get way to translate the months

Comment: Thanks so much, now everything is translated, but there is something that I do not like how it looks. Apparently it takes the first letter of the dayname and shows it as the name day in the header and in my language all the days start with a "D", so this is how it looks like: https://i.imgur.com/xc0spHB.png. Do you know if it is possible to show Wed instead of W (Wednesday) for instance?

Comment: Look edited answer, a way to get 3 letters in picker.

Comment: I have just tried it, but I get "Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of undefined" when I click on the datepicker: https://i.imgur.com/RrgyUtu.png

Comment: Ok, i just updated - my previous solution was for ext-5+, look for my edited answer right now